# Question whose answer is a subset of other question

Tags: discussion, answers

This question pertains to [Change location of vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26021612/2517719)

Basically, this question required an answer that would also apply to [Change default location of vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7109667/2517719), a slightly more general version of the same question.  I asked the question and when I received an acceptable answer, I upvoted and accepted it.  I then posted what I did to get it to work as an answer to [Change default location of vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7109667/2517719) and voted to close mine as a duplicate.

My thinking was that this information should be consolidated to one question.  However, I feel guilty that any upvotes on the hopefully ultimately authoritative version ([Change default location of vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7109667/2517719)) would go to me, rather than the initial author (though I do think that my version is better because it gives an explicit answer rather than simply pointing to docs).  Did I do the right thing, or was there a better way to handle this?

PS: I apologize if this has been addressed before.  I did my best to look but I didn't quite know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag the post and ask a moderator to merge your question into the duplicate question.  This will copy the answer to your question to the canonical question.

Also note that copying someone else's answer around to other related questions is not appropriate.  If the questions are duplicate questions they should simply be closed as such, rather than having the answers also duplicated between them.  If the questions are different enough to not be duplicates, then the answers should be tailored to the specific question, highlighting the differences, and any work taken from another answer should be cited appropriately.

Comment: @JonK Added a paragraph on the subject.

Comment: @Jonk, the original author pointed me to a blog post, but didn't explain it or give an explicit answer.  The answer I posted was not a simple c/p, but instead the result of me crafting a solution that differed in important ways from what was in the blog.  I also explained the differences between this approach and the others already presented.  Would this case be an exception to that rule?  Because I'm worried that simply merging his answer in wouldn't provide enough information for another person to easily understand and apply it.

Comment: @Floegipoky If you don't think that that answer would be a valuable addition to the canonical question then don't flag for a merge.  It's a feature that you would use explicitly if you felt that it would be a valuable addition to the canonical.

Comment: @Servy, would it be appropriate to edit his answer to provide the explicit solution and explanation, and then request the merge?

Comment: @Floegipoky No.  That would be a radical change to the post.

Comment: @Servy So then was my initial action of flagging as duplicate and posting a more appropriately detailed answer to the canonical question appropriate?  If not then what should I do?

Comment: @Floegipoky If you consider the answer to be incomplete, then yes.